# How can I get a two-way unit / currency converter?

Tags: javascript, html, currency

I'm trying to build a very simple two-way currency converter.

I currently have this HTML:

```
    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" value="0" />

    <input id="result" name="discount" type="text" value="0" />
```

and this javascript:

```
    $('input').on("click",function () {
    $("#result").val(parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10) *  520);
    });
```

I would like the converter to work both ways, so that the user can enter the amount in either field, [like this](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=currency%20converter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a trigger [on keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/). That way, if the #amount-box is triggered, you get the result in the #result box and vice-versa.

```
<input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" value="0" />
<input id="result" name="discount" type="text" value="0" />
```

And:

```
$("#amount").keyup(function(){
    var calculated = $(this).val() * 2;
    $("#result").val(calculated);
});

$("#result").keyup(function(){
    var calculated = $(this).val() / 2;
    $("#amount").val(calculated);
});
```

Comment: @rory in that case, use keypress instead of keydown. Or as you said, onchange (but then it's not "realtime" converted)

Comment: @Roboroads - ah yes, you are correct. From the Jquery page... " For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus."

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [$.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event

So your code would look something like this:

```
$("#amount").change(function() {
    //do your conversions here...
    } );
```

And then do the same for the other `#result` field

Answer (score 0):

You can have still one event handler, but use `change` event and check using id of changed input which input you should update.

```
$('input').on("change",function () {
  if (this.id === 'result') {
    $("#amount").val(parseInt($("#result").val(), 10) /  520);
  } else if (this.id === 'amount') {
    $("#result").val(parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10) *  520);
  }
});
```